# mysql - row time difference again

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to calculate a time difference between 2 rows - but it's a bit trickier then usual. A user, when enters, receives a `temporally_id`. This Id is not unique - it means that after this user has left, a new used might get the same `temporally_id`, but **usually**(see explanation below) only after the first user has left. The entrance table looks like this (entrance_states - 1:enter, 2:exit):

```
| temporally_id | entrance_state | entrance_date    |
-----------------------------------------------------
|    111        |       1        | 2017-01-01 10:20 |
|    222        |       1        | 2017-01-01 11:00 |
|    222        |       2        | 2017-01-01 11:20 |
|    222        |       1        | 2017-01-01 18:00 |
|    111        |       2        | 2017-01-01 21:00 |
|    111        |       1        | 2017-01-01 22:15 |
|    222        |       2        | 2017-01-02 01:00 |
|    111        |       2        | 2017-01-02 02:15 |
```

As you can see - the user can also stay inside until the next day.
My wish would be a following result:

```
| temporally_id | entrance_date    | timediff |
-----------------------------------------------
|    111        | 2017-01-01 10:20 | 11,50 h  |
|    222        | 2017-01-01 11:00 |  0,33 h  |
|    222        | 2017-01-01 18:00 |  7,00 h  |
|    111        | 2017-01-01 22:15 |  4,00 h  |
```

So basically I want a time difference. The trickiest part is that sometimes, the "exit" is not being logged - so in the table it looks like the state 1 follows after an other state 1 for the same temporally_id (which is again not normal and should not be). There for I must consider this failure and check whether the state 1 is followed by state 2.

And here is my SQL Query:

```
SELECT avg(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,A.date,B.date)/60 ) as `diff`
FROM (SELECT 
        entrance_date as date,
        temporally_id
        FROM `entrance` 
        WHERE entrance_state = 1
        order by temporally_id asc, entrance_date asc ) A
LEFT JOIN        
     (SELECT 
        entrance_date as date, 
        temporally_id
        FROM `entrance` 
        WHERE  action_id = 2
        order by temporally_id asc, activity_date asc ) 
        B ON A.temporally_id = B.temporally_id
```

Unfortunately this is not giving me what I need.

Comment: This is a really hard problem, fraught with edge cases and unusual circumstances.  It is one of the few times that I'll suggest writing the logic using a cursor or in the application.

Comment: I suggest adding a user_id to the table so you can determine when they leave rather than inferring it through the data flow.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't add a user id to them - at least not at this point

Answer (score 0):

"temporally_id" is a misuse of the English language.  What you mean is "temporary_id".

You are not going to be able to make this "temporary_id" idea to work, because you cannot atomically determine that a "temporary_id" is unused *and* reuse it.  So, you *will* have race conditions where two users who entered at about the same time received the same "temporary_id".

In any case, if you insist on trying, then you need to reduce the complexity of this problem by eliminating the cases where the "exit" has not been logged.  So, make one pass through your table, select all rows where "exit" was not logged, and set their "exit" time to be the "entry" time plus, say, 20 minutes.  (A usual web session timeout.)

Comment: Thanks - regarding the "temorary"-word I was unawair :) If I'll write a loop in my application which would search and edit this table, then I could also use this loop to calculate this time difference. But may be this is a better way, since the problem is so unusual

Answer (score 0):

Instead of processing the records based on `entrance_state`, I would recommend processing the records based on `temporally_id` and `entrance_date` e.g.:

```
SELECT *
FROM entrance
ORDER BY temporally_id, entrance_date
```

This would give you the result sorted by id and date, you can then write a logic inside your application or in a stored procedure that will keep track of previously processed record, compare `temporally_id` and `entrance_state` of current record against it and output/ignore it accordingly.

Comment: Yes - this is also what @gordon-linoff suggested.  Writing a logic inside an application is always an option, but I wanted to see whether there is a smarter way to do this only using SQL